# Is there a simple way to introduce a lifetime to my existing macros?

Tags: rust, macros

I have structs which implement the traits from std::ops like Add, Mul, etc. There are many of these implementations on many combinations of different types, as well as all combinations of their borrows and mutable borrows.

To make my life easier I have macros that take these types as arguments and implement the operations. However, I now need to change some of my types to have lifetimes. Is there a way to create a namespace like a module block that contains a lifetime, so that I can pass 'MyType<'a>' into a macro instead of redoing every implementation in the macro to contain a lifetime?

Some types don't need lifetimes so if it comes down to needing new macros I will need to quadruple the number of existing macros to account for whether the left or right hand side of the operation need a lifetime, which makes me wonder if there is an easier solution.

Comment: Have you considered looking at how the standard library does it?  For example, `Add` is implemented for the primitive numeric types via an [`add_impl`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/arith.rs.html#92-105) macro which emits the owned impl and then delegates to a more general [`forward_ref_binop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/internal_macros.rs.html#23-59) macro that emits the borrowed impls.

Comment: If I were to copy that setup I would still need to have 4 versions of each macro to cover the cases of types that may need lifetimes on the left, right, both, or neither. (Like MyStruct<'a> + u32 or MyStruct<'a> + MyStruct<'a> etc.). But I should probably model my macros after the standard library so I appreciate the links. @eggyal